# Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE when using Train in Caret

Tags: r, dataframe, neural-network, r-caret

I have a training set that looks like

```
Name       Day         Area         X    Y    Month Night
ATTACK    Monday   LA           -122.41 37.78   8      0
VEHICLE  Saturday  CHICAGO      -1.67    3.15   2      0
MOUSE     Monday   TAIPEI       -12.5    3.1    9      1
```

`Name` is the outcome/dependent variable. I converted `Name`, `Area` and `Day` into factors, but I wasn't sure if I was supposed to for `Month` and `Night`, which only take on integer values 1-12 and 0-1, respectively.

I then convert the data into matrix

```
ynn <- model.matrix(~Name , data = trainDF)
mnn <- model.matrix(~ Day+Area +X + Y + Month + Night, data = trainDF)
```

I then setup tuning the parameters

```
nnTrControl=trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",number = 3,repeats=5,verboseIter = TRUE, returnData = FALSE, returnResamp = "all", classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = multiClassSummary,allowParallel = TRUE)
nnGrid = expand.grid(.size=c(1,4,7),.decay=c(0,0.001,0.1))
model <- train(y=ynn, x=mnn, method='nnet',linout=TRUE, trace = FALSE, trControl = nnTrControl,metric="logLoss", tuneGrid=nnGrid)
```

However, I get the error `Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE` for the `model<-train`

I also get a similar error if I use `xgboost` instead of `nnet`

Anyone know whats causing this?

Comment: Not sure about the error, but you should convert `Month` and `Night` to factor variables too.

Comment: I just did that. That didn't solve the error

Comment: `y` should be a numeric or factor vector containing the outcome for each sample, not a matrix. Try `train(y = trainDF$Name, ...`; it gives different errors with your example data but perhaps it will work with a full dataset.

Comment: Trying that I get the error `At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name; This will cause errors when class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to  ATTACK, VEHICLE, MOUSE, ... . Please use factor levels that can be used as valid R variable names  (see ?make.names for help).` But `Name` already is a factor, according to `str(trainDF$Name)`. So I don't understand this error

Comment: I see, maybe its because some the values in `Name` are invalid. Some of its values are `Hit Run`, `Home Run`, etc. So maybe the spaces are causing the problem? How can I fix that?

Comment: @user5739619, so, did my answer help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`y` should be a numeric or factor vector containing the outcome for each sample, not a matrix. Using

```
train(y = make.names(trainDF$Name), ...)
```

helps, where `make.names` modifies values so that they could be valid variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Even though in the help file of `train` said either maxtrix or data frame would be expected, but you can try to convert the matrix to a data frame:

```
model <- train(y=ynn, x=as.data.frame(mnn), method='nnet',linout=TRUE, trace = FALSE, trControl = nnTrControl,metric="logLoss", tuneGrid=nnGrid)
```