# "nrow(x) == n is not TRUE" when using train in Caret; already set as factors

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm using the dataset found here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Qualitative_Bankruptcy

When running code:
    library(caret)

```
bank <- read.csv("Qualitative_Bankruptcy.data.txt", header=FALSE, na.strings = "?", 
             strip.white = TRUE)

x=bank[1:6]
y=bank[7]

bank.knn <- train(x, y, method= "knn", trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
```

I get the following error:
    Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE

The only example I've found is [Error: nrow(x) == n is not TRUE when using Train in Caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527492/error-nrowx-n-is-not-true-when-using-train-in-caret) ; my Y is already a factor vector with two classes, all the X features are factors as well. I've tried using as.matrix and as.data.frame on both the X and Y without success.

nrow(x) is equal to 250, but I'm not sure what the n is referring to in the package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`y` is not actually a vector, but a data.frame with one column because `bank[7]` does not convert the 7th column into a vector, so `length(y)` is 1. Use `bank[, 7]` instead. It does not make a difference for `x` but it could as well be generated by `bank[, 1:6]`.

Additionally to make KNN work you probably have to convert the `x` data.frame that consists of factor variables to numeric dummy variables.

```
x=model.matrix(~. - 1, bank[, 1:6])
y=bank[, 7]
bank.knn <- train(x, y, method= "knn", 
                  trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))
```

Comment: so "-1" inside the model.matrix takes out the last column? and if i put "-2" does that take out the last two columns or the 2nd to last column? can i make it more dynamic by calling a variable name instead of an integer?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions The `-1` is special formula syntax for excluding the intercept, which would be a column of only ones. You can of course substitute `[, 1:6]` with your choice of variables. There are lots of [tutorials](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) on how to subset data frames and matrices in R.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a caret user but I think you have two problems. The extraction method you used did not deliver an atomic vector but rahter a list that contained a vector. If you asked for length(y) you get 1 rather than 250. The first error is easily solved by changing to this definition of `y`:

```
 y <- bank[[7]]  # extract a vector rather than a sublist
```

Then things get messy. The KNN method expects continuous data (and the error messages you get indicate the caret's author considers it a "regression method" and you are passing factor data, so you therefore need to choose a classification method instead.